# Get notification when new file is added to folder (python)

Tags: python, directory, watchdog

We have a sharepoint folder that we have to refresh every now and then to see if new files were added. By refreshing I mean clicking the small refresh button if in folder or going out and back in again to see new files.

I wonder if in python we can write some code to say check every 15 minutes, or every minute, to see if a new file was added and if so, generate a popup notification (or like in windows 10 notification center).

I know there is watchdog, but that is designed to run code when there are file changes.

Comment: What operating system is this on? Also, why exactly is watchdog not suitable for your task?

Comment: @davidz it is windows 10. Does watchdog allow for notification to generate?

Comment: @plshelpimpoor _Does watchdog allow for notification to generate?_ Probably not, you would just use a different library to handle that aspect.